# What does Python's open do when errors=None?

Tags: python, file

The documentation for the [`open` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) states that the default for the `errors` argument is `None`.  However it doesn't say anywhere what action that will result in; it only lists the various strings you can use in its place.  Clicking through to the documentation for [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) is similarly unhelpful.

Is the default behavior documented somewhere, or is it up to the whims of whatever developer last worked on `open`?  What happens when you read a byte stream that's invalid according to the selected encoding?

Comment: It says in the documentation that `None` is equivalent to `'strict'`.

Comment: **'strict' to raise a ValueError exception if there is an encoding error. The default value of None has the same effect.**

Comment: I agree that they should just use the string `'strict'` as the default directly. The use of `None` for default values to avoid issues with mutable defaults is a bit of a cargo-cult tradition.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how I missed that.  You should leave that as an answer.

Comment: I don't think it's worth answering. The question is based on a misreading.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree completely.  Explicit is better than implicit?

Comment: @Barmar I don't think it's so much of a misreading, the information is there but very well hidden.  I can't be the first person to wonder this.

Comment: The right place to raise the issue, then, is probably https://discuss.python.org/c/documentation/26 .

Comment: You said "it doesn't say anywhere". It does, you just missed it.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments on the question, the answer really is in the documentation but is well hidden.  It's not listed explicitly under its own bullet point, but as part of the information for the `'strict'` choice.

> The default value of None has the same effect.

Comment: A lot of the Python docs are like that. It’s all there, just somewhat informal and in the form of prose. If you read it all, you usually understand it. Just trying to zero in on bullet points is not how to read the Python docs.

Comment: @deceze in this case I already knew what each of the options did, I wasn't going to read them thoroughly. Documenting the default behavior is important enough that it should stand out.